# How to compile qemu with usb suport

Tags: usb, virtualization, qemu

I have recently downloaded qemu and compiled qemu 2.3.0.
I can compile and  install just fine, but I cant figure out how to get USB support. I have installed libusb 1.0.9 but when I run configure for quemu, it still says there is no usb support.

```
/qemu-2.3.0$ ./configure
...
libusb            no
usb net redir     no
...
```

how can i get usb support with qemu?

***UPDATE:****
I followed this advice, and not I have usb net redir but still not libusb

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
sudo apt-get install libusbredirparser-dev

and again

./configure
[...]
libusb            yes
usb net redir     yes
[...]
```

Comment: The "UPDATE" text is conflicting. it says "still not libusb", but the configure output says `libusb   yes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the development library of `libusb` and `libusbredirparser-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
sudo apt-get install libusbredirparser-dev
```

and again

```
./configure
[...]
libusb            yes
usb net redir     yes
[...]
```

Comment: I will check that out

Comment: Interestingly, on (X)Ubuntu 16.04, I had to install `libusb-1.0-0-dev` instead of `libusb-dev`.